# How to hardcode Document Node value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hardcode the document node value in Javascript code but I get exception.

I have the below Javascript code. The querySelector returns unordered list

```
var documentNode = document.querySelector('#subordinate').firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
documentNode.setAttribute('id','document');
```

I want to hardcode the documentNode variable value for development purpose. I tried as below:

```
var documentNode = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<ul><li class=\"active js-active\"><a href=\"https://website.com/Home\" class=\"active\">Home</a></li><li><a href=\"https://website.com/page2\">Page2</a></li></ul>", 'text/html');
documentNode.setAttribute('id','document'); //Exception occurs here
```

Then I get exception at the `setAttribute()` code

```
documentNode.setAttribute is not a function
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code?

Comment: `.parseFromString` returns a Document object, it doesn't have the said method. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what HTML code, his question has nothing to do with the HTML. @firstpostcommenter please post `console.log(documentNode)` after the parsing, before attempting to assign attribute

Comment: @Teemu a whole document object? not just a DOM node? I am assuming, that he is expecting `<ul>` to be the element in the node

Comment: @Dellirium Pretty much a [whole document](https://jsfiddle.net/bm4knuhy/), with `html`, `head` and `body` elements etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set an ID on a document object. You can set it on contents:

```js
var documentNode = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<ul><li class=\"active js-active\"><a href=\"https://website.com/Home\" class=\"active\">Home</a></li><li><a href=\"https://website.com/page2\">Page2</a></li></ul>", 'text/html');

var ul = documentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
ul.setAttribute('id', 'subordinate'); // setting the ID

console.log(
  documentNode.querySelector('#subordinate')
    .firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.querySelector("a").href
);
```

Comment: how to set the ID for <ul>?